# Match an array value with a string and return the array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

I have an array like this

```
 0 => array:4 [▼
    "Name" => "Aroma Therapy - 45 minutes"
    "ID" => "1000000015"
    "Price" => "50.00"
    "Category" => "Aroma"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "Name" => "Aroma Therapy - 60 Minutes"
    "ID" => "0000000003"
    "Price" => "100.00"
    "Category" => "Aroma"
```

What I am trying to achieve is that, whenever a user searches for `'therapy'` or `'aroma'`, I want to match with this array's name and return it's price and ID.

I tried using `strpos()` `strstr()` and regular expressions as well, I can find if the search matches or not but I cannot get the functionality of returning the array when matched.

So, if a user searches for `'therapy'`, I want to return the two arrays above, in a variable called `$result`. So I can access it's name, ID and price like this

```
$result->Name, $result->ID, $result->Price
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this kind of functionality?

Comment: @WilliamPerron If you read my question, I have mentioned that I have tried using strpost(), strstr() and regular expressions, but I am unable to return the matched array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php), you can get array items

> `stripos` — Find the position of the first occurrence of a
>   case-insensitive substring in a string
>
> `array_filter` — Filters elements of an array using a callback
>   function

```
// keyword to be searched
$keyword = 'aroma';

// you will get all array items of matched 
$result_array = array_filter($array, function($item) use ($keyword) {
        return ( stripos($item['Name'], $keyword) !== false );
});

// to convert to object
$object = json_decode( json_encode($result_array) );
```